# How to adjust reverse proxy backends in runtime?

Tags: web-applications, cluster-computing, load-balancing

I have the following problem: a set of nodes running docker with applications. Sometimes i may need to stop the running containers on one node but i do not want down times so i need something to redirect traffic to other instances or newly spawned ones. I do not want the current sessions to be affected(they may go on until the client disconnects but new clients are redirected to other instances). I have an application on every docker node that must be able to find out when there are no more active sessions to the containers so it can clean the node (delete the containers).

I think i should use a load balancer for this but i need one that is able to register/delete nodes in runtime. Also, it would be desirable to be able to retrieve the list of active sessions for a node so i could check if it is empty to proceed with the containers deletion.

Any ideas?

Kind regards

Answer (score 0):

Have you checked Docker Swarm with a discovery backend.  I personally, have not taken that route since I am using NetflixOSS to perform service discovery and I am using Eureka to discover services rather than containers that are active.  But here is the link
https://docs.docker.com/swarm/

Discovery Backends: https://docs.docker.com/swarm/discovery/
Hope that leads you in the right direction.